# .NET Core Identity - Scaffold pages without overriding existing files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a .NET Core 2.2 MVC app using Identity.  Since I'm using Visual Studio for Mac I had to use the CLI to scaffold out the identity files.  Initially I only needed a few files so I used the following command to generate the files I needed:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files="Account.Manage.ChangePassword;Account.Register;Account.ResetPassword;Account.ResetPasswordConfirmation;Account.Manage.SetPassword;Account.Manage.Index"
```

I'm now trying to generate another file by running:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files="Account.Manage.EnableAuthenticator"
```

but I get the following error:
*The below files exist. Use '--force' to overwrite: Areas/Identity/Data/SAFDtoolsIdentityDbContext.cs
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_ManageNav.cshtml
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/ManageNavPages.cs*

Is it possible to generate additional files without overriding existing files?  I don't want to lose any customizations I already made.

Also, if I use --force will only the 3 files in the error get overwritten or will every file I already generated be overwritten??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each file name(for example `Account.Manage.EnableAuthenticator`) contains several files which list in `identitygeneratorfilesconfig.json` templete:

https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/blob/release/2.2/src/VS.Web.CG.Mvc/Identity/bootstrap4_identitygeneratorfilesconfig.json#L301

Currently it seems will overwrite the existing files and not find option to disable the behavior , you can use the `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles` , it will show the exist files which need to use `--force` to overwrite .

> Also, if I use --force will only the 3 files in the error get overwritten or will every file I already generated be overwritten??

It will overwrite the 3 files and you can copy/save the customize part of codes , paste that part of codes to new created files .